# How to return AJAX data correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to return the current page data but when I console the function, it displays something like:

> `Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions·

```
var vm = this;
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  .withOption('ajax', {
    // Either you specify the AjaxDataProp here
    url: 'api/bank_recon/fetch_trx',
    type: 'POST',

    data: function(d) {
      var api = this.api();
      var pgNo = api.page.info();
      var currPg = pgNo.page;
      d.draw = currPg;

      return JSON.stringify(d);
    }
  })
```

Comment: your API link `api/bank_recon/fetch_trx` works right? This works when you hit this on postman?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47615114/typeerror-caller-callee-and-arguments-properties-may-not-be-accessed-on

Comment: What is `DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()`?

Comment: this is not angular